# spring boot multiple servers login issue

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

We have a spring boot project used to use only one server. We recently switching to use two servers for the same spring boot application. Now the users are frequently asked to login. We found out if a user logged in one server and a new request is sent to another server, this would happen.

I am sure this is very common issue with solutions. Could anyone point me to the right direction how to fix the login issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like you might need to put both apps behind a proxy server or load balancer that is able to maintain sessions with the original app/server the initially connect to/from

Comment: If using sticky sessions with your load balancer/proxy server is not an option then you could look at [Spring Session] (https://spring.io/projects/spring-session) with a distributed cache like Redis or Hazelcast.